# Randomized ReLU in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, activation-function

It is proved that Randomized ReLU, as well as Parametric ReLU, perform better compared to ReLU in CIFAR-10, CIFAR-100 and NDSB datasets. While Keras has provided documentation on how to use PReLU, I was not able to find one for RReLU. Can someone brief about the usage of Randomized ReLU activation in Keras?

Below is the description of RReLU from the paper arXiv:1505.00853v2.

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the formula for RReLU?

Comment: I have added it! @rvinas

Comment: TAke a look at this repo https://github.com/JGuillaumin/one_week_one_paper/tree/master/week_46_drop_activation

Comment: Have already tried the syntax given in that notebook which is activation='randomized-relu'. But it throws an error saying Unknown activation function.